# unable to import tensorflow on Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to install `tensorflow` on my MacBook Pro but I keep getting this error message when I run any code that has `import tensorflow`. I am using Python 3.7.3 on macOS Mojave.

I learnt from some other solutions online how to solve the problem like try `pip install tensorflow==2.0.0-alpha0 --ignore-installed`. It worked for some but not for me.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = data.load_data()
```

Comment: What error do you have when you try "pip install tensorflow==2.0.0-alpha0 --ignore-installed" ?

Answer (score 0):

install [anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/) and try this:

Create Virtual Environment

```
conda create --name tensorflow-env python=3.7.3
```

Activate the environment

```
activate tensorflow-env
```

Install tensorflow

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

Test your installation

```
import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant("hello TensorFlow!")
sess=tf.Session() 
print sess.run(hello)
```

output:

"hello TensorFlow!"

Comment: didn't solve my problem I got the following error when I used the conda interpreter

Comment: something related to compression file failure. I don't exactly remember

Comment: i need more info